# C++ Transform string into its ASCII representation

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple packet parser. For testing, I've prepared data in format as followed:

```
std::string input = "0903000000330001 ... ";
```

and I need to transform it into something like this

```
0x09 0x03 0x00 0x00 ...
```

Could you help me how I should construct the new string?

I already tried these ...

```
std::string newInput = "\x09\x03\x00 ... ";
std::string newInput = "\u0009\u0003\u0000 ...";
```

but the program returns that the size of this string is only two.

```
std::cout << newInput.size() << std::endl;
 > 2
```

I'm really missing or misunderstanding something...

Comment: Why not use what's the most intuitive and simple ie. array of characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string` *can* hold a string with embedded nul characters, but you have to tell its length in the constructor:

```
std::string NewInput("\x09\x03\x00 ... ", number_of_characters);
```

Otherwise, `std::string` will use `strlen` to compute the length, and stop at the `\x00`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C, and to some extent also in C++, are terminated with the null character. So if the `'\x00'` (aka `'\0'`) character is encountered, that's taken to be the end of the string. If you're mainly interested in the numerical values of each character, you may want to use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` or similar instead. `std::string` can handle null characters (you need to use the function overloads with explicit lengths) but for example `c_str()` may not behave as you might expect.